# RuntimeError: could not find any library for SDL2_ttf

Tags: python, sdl, game-engine, python-3.3, pysdl2

I have a problem with pysdl2. I'm trying to launch examples from site-packages\sdl2\examples and see this error:

```
c:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\sdl2\examples>python draw.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "draw.py", line 10, in <module>
    import sdl2.ext as sdl2ext
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sdl2\ext\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
        from .common import *
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sdl2\ext\common.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .. import sdlttf
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sdl2\sdlttf.py", line 40, in <module>
    os.getenv("PYSDL2_DLL_PATH"))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sdl2\dll.py", line 51, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("could not find any library for %s" % libinfo)
RuntimeError: could not find any library for SDL2_ttf
```

But files which don't use sdl2_ttf (such as sdl2hello.py) work correctly and without errors. I have no idea how to solve it.

Additional info: WinXP SP3 32bit

Answer (score 4):

This error seems to be the result of the script not finding the `SDL2_ttf` package.

Following [the instructions of the PySDL2 manual](http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#on-importing), you must have set a `PYSDL2_DLL_PATH` like so:

```
# Win32 platforms
set PYSDL2_DLL_PATH=C:\path\to\fancy_project\third_party

# Unix/Posix-alike environments - bourne shells
export PYSDL2_DLL_PATH=/path/to/fancy_project/third_party

# Unix/Posix-alike environments - C shells
setenv PYSDL2_DLL_PATH /path/to/fancy_project/third_party
```

so you just have to get the `SDL2_ttf` package here: http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/ and download the runtime library corresponding to your system (http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-win32-x86.zip) and add it in the same folder where `SDL2.dll` is. Check out at `C:\your-python-directory\DLLs`

It's the same with `SDL_image`, `SDL_mixer`, `SDL_net` and `SDL_gfx` (on another website though for this last one).

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue

```
brew install sdl2
```

Solved my problem on OSX